# Does a real symmetric matrix is a positive definite real symmetric matrix by exponential map？

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, positive-definite, matrix-exponential

If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, $\forall r\in \mathbb{R}$, can we have $\exp(rA)$ is a positive definite real symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Write $A = P D P^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal and $P^{-1} = P^T$. Then obviously
\begin{equation}
\exp(r A) = P \exp(r D) P ^{-1}
\end{equation}
is symmetric and positive definite because if $D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)$ then
\begin{equation}
\exp(r D) = \operatorname{diag}(\exp(r\lambda_1),\cdots,\exp(r\lambda_n))
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me why exp(rD) is positive definite？

Comment: $\exp(r D)$ is a diagonal matrix and all the terms on the diagonal are $> 0$, hence it is positive definite.

Comment: But the matrix [(1 0)(0 -1)] is not positive definite?

Comment: It's not the exponential of a diagonal matrix because it has a -1 on the diagonal. The terms of $\exp(r D)$ are $\exp(r \lambda_i) > 0$ on the diagonal.

Comment: Thank you so much.